# Ubuntu mouse not working well and everything is running slowly on good computer. (i5, 8GB, 7950)

Tags: usb, mouse, system-installation

I am giving Ubuntu a try. Here is the process I went through.

I first installed it following [this guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HQvbH0UlQU).  I put the files on one USB and then installed them onto another. My mouse was moving around the screen just fine and once and a while would be able to click on something but then it either did nothing or took a very long time to load. I looked it up and discovered USBs arent super great for running Ubuntu. So I then installed it onto a 500GB WD HDD. I got the same results if not worse.

Please help me out. I would love to support Open Source but wont be able to if I cant get past these first steps.

EDIT: FIXED SEE COMMENTS

Comment: Maybe it is graphic problem.. What's your graphic hardware? Is it NVIDIA or Radeon? Or is it intel HD?
Sometimes the first two makes this problem.

Comment: @user1391782 Radeon 7950. If I were to install driver updates would it help?

Comment: As I have experienced, when you use a native driver something like Gallium, my ubuntu seems so slow. But, whenever I install nvidia driver package, it will be smoother and faster.
Compared to using intel HD, it will be no problem. I'm not very sure about Radeon. I recommend you to install the driver, but I don't think it is risk-less.
Hope there'll be a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was using a rat 7 which is apparently super incompatible with Ubuntu. It did however run just fine once I followed advice from [this blog](http://delightlylinux.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/using-the-cyborg-r-a-t-7-with-ubuntu/) which suggests using Compiz Config Settings Manager (ccsm) to make some tweaks and also to use the mouse on a light surface.

I also used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=871eM-GcdyI)

create a file and enter the text into it:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/910-rat.conf

Section "Input Class"
    Identifier "R.A.T."
    MatchProduct "R.A.T.7|R.A.T.9"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option "Buttons" "17"
    Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 0 0 8 9 7 6 12 0 0 0 16 17"
    Option "AutoReleaseButtons" "13 14 15"
    Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as correct so that this question doesn't keep showing up in Unanswered.